# Deleting text from Word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

How a specific text can be deleted from Word using macro ?

```
Dim ActualParagraph As Paragraph
Set ActualParagraph = Selection.Paragraphs(1)
...
```

I tried

```
ActualParagraph.Range.Characters(1).Delete Unit:=wdCharacter
```

in cycle to delete first X characters but the issue is that if there's a space, Word automatically removes it with the character before it therefore you can't easily calculate how many times such .Delete should be called.

I tried

```
ActualParagraph.Range.Delete(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1)
```

but it deletes the whole paragraph regardless of number of characters in it.

Is there any reliable way where I can specify, e.g., deleting from character X to character Y everything. I can't also find anything useful in MSDN or anywhere else. I don't want to delete by searching and then deleting selected text.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without VBA. Ctrl+H, Find: "sampleText", Replace: "".
It will replace "sampleText" to nothing.

However, here is the code with the use of a variable in ".Text =":

```
Option Explicit
Sub replaceSampleToNothing()
    Dim sample
    sample = "sampleText"

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = sample
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is deleting the blank after it deletes the character you ask it to is probably because of the "Smart Cut & Paste" options, which do things like delete the blank after a word when you delete the word itself. See File -> Options -> Advanced -> Cut, Copy and Paste section -> "Smart Cut & Paste" and its options.

The other problem is that it appears, when given a non-empty selection/range of text, Selection.Delete ignores the count you give it and just deletes the selection (the documentation is clear as mud on this).